# Text Contrast Issue: How to enhance a hero image section?

Tags: accessibility, text, contrast

I'm using a hero image as a landing page for a ecommerce site. Here's what it looks like so far:

[image]

I'm having issues with the text's contrast over the background image. Any ideas on how I can make the text stand out more?

Comment: Make the hero image more darker I guest

Answer (score 3):

That background image has a lot of contrast in it so it's hard to get contrast over it. These are some colors from that background

[image]

A block of color would get rid of the contrast issues. This is a color from the background

[image]

Comment: Instead of a solid color,  you can make a gradient overlay that goes 50% transparent at top to 100% transparent halfway down. Manage the percentages to suit. The color could come from a darker shade of what's in the photo, or if the photo will change, a gray can be used.

Comment: The "lorem ipsum" subtext would need the background block too.